# error establishing a database connection and Error Invalid default value for type datetime

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

am facing a very serious and mysterious issue with mySQL database. Could any body help me at the earliest?

Let me elaborate the issue -

Its a WordPress website running on Godaddy VPS having php 7.4 and mySQL 5.2.1 versions. There is a coincidence, when  a newsletter sent from constant contact email marketing portal, this website went down  (error log - mysqli_query(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in /wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 2459). it works all the time and only goes down with error "connection to database error".
It works only when I repaired and optimized database  using cpanel.
I tried all possible ways but not able to figure out the real cause.

Few more errors while optimizing database - Note Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead
Error Invalid default value for 'log_date_gmt'
Status Operation failed

I am wondering why all this happens, and it only happens when newsletter sent from CC portal, otherwise it works perfectly fine. I am trying to fix it for many days, I replace all plugins, core files and even theme but nothing work for me.

Please help and save me.

I updated WP core files, plugins and optimized database but nothing work for me..

Comment: This *gone away* message means the MySQL database process crashed.  The subsquent connection failures happen while it is restarting. You say you have a VPS. That means there's somebody around who has shell access to the server machine. Get that person to look at the system logs and MySQL server logs; they often explain what happened.

Comment: What do Constant Contact emails have to do with this? Is some plugin in your WordPress instance trying to *receive and process* these emails? Are they going to a large audience who click on links in the messages and overload your server? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: You should upgrade MySQL to a more recent version, see the [WordPress requirements](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/): MySQL version 5.7 or greater OR MariaDB version 10.4 or greater.

Comment: That version 5.2.1 has to be wrong. The "not support optimize" message is clear evidence of InnoDB usage. Still, GoDaddy likes to run old versions in their tech stack.

Comment: "at the earliest"—please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/354577) (TL;DR: It's never okay.)

Answer (score 1):

*Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead* is normal. The `OPTIMIZE TABLE xxx` function was specific to the older MyISAM access method in MySQL, and this warning gets issued when you do it to an InnoDB table. Everything works correctly.

*Error Invalid default value for 'log_date_gmt'* happens because WordPress's database design has many `DATETIME` columns with default values of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. It's necessary to set your sql mode to allow zero dates to operate on WordPress tables.

WordPress issues the following command whenever it connects to MySQL. It updates [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html). You can issue the same command before doing anything like rebuilding WordPress tables, and the *invalid default value" errors will stop.

```sql
SET @@sql_mode := REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'NO_ZERO_DATE', '');
```

As for the MySQL server crash caused somehow (wtf???) by an email blast, I would suspect RAM or HDD / SSD drive space ran out. Look at the logs on the server machine and try to figure out what happened. They are usually quite clear. Or, ask GoDaddy tech support to do it. You may need to migrate to a more capable hosting setup, especially if your site has grown a lot.

Comment: This is a very accurate, nice answer +1

Comment: Thank you, Jones. I appreciate your help, let me implement it and check if it works..

Comment: Hi Jones, We have upgraded the server to the latest software. Apache Version - 2.4.57, MySQL version is 8.0.34, PHP 7.4. Unfortunately, the problem is not fixed.  There are no such errors while optimizing the database but still having downtime and error mysqli_query(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in public_html/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line 2459.

Please help!

Thank you.